# Best data structure store sets of numbers from a text file

Tags: c++, data-structures, set

I have an assignment where I need to find minimum set cover of some points. I want to be able to store each row of numbers in an individual sets but I do not know the best data structure or approach to do this. I have the number of rows there will be. For example, the .txt file will look like this:

1 2 3 4 5 6

5 6 8 9

1 4 7 10

2 5 7 8 11

3 6 9 12

10 11

Is there a way to dynamically create multiple data structures to store each row of numbers? I was thinking something that works like this if it exists:

```
list<int> myList[6]; // create 6 lists
myList[0].insert(num); // insert numbers into this list
myList[1].insert(num); //insert numbers into the second list
```

I do not want to individually create lists because in a .txt file, there can be up to 300 sets of numbers.

edit: my main issue is figuring out how to dynamically create some data structure, preferably if it works with std::set_union since it looks useful to my assignment

Comment: This sounds like an application of [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), which models the mathematical set rather than a linked list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control the number of lists programmatically, you can use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of datasets. So in your case the declaration would be

```
std::vector<std::list<int>> lists(6);
```

Adding new, empty lists to the lists set is done by

```
lists.push_back({}).
```